# How is FreeType calculating advance?

Tags: c++, truetype, freetype

I am trying to figure out how the FreeType Library is calculating the `FT_GlyphSlotRec_`'s `advance` variable. According to the comment blocks above this structure, this variable would be the same as the `horiAdvance` variable further explained [here](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step2.html), which is contained within the `FT_Glyph_Metrics_` structure.

In any case, take the typical Arial narrow font as an example. It can be found in C:\Windows\Fonts\ARIALN.TTF. Uploading it to any of the web based TTF file editors ([option 1](http://mathew-kurian.github.io/CharacterMap/), [option 2](http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/)), or using your own program that can interpret TTF files (fontforge, etc) you can see the Advance for the '!' character is clearly defined as 467.

I am running the following code and when I read `FT_GlyphSlotRec_`'s `advance.x` value, I get a value of 1472. Obviously this is not the same as 467. Am I misinterpreting what this represents? Or am I using the FreeType library incorrectly?

I am retyping the code I used to get 1472 from a computer without internet, so please forgive me for any mundane syntax errors.

```
#include <string>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

using namespace std;

int main() {
  FT_Uint font_height = 100;
  FT_Library ft;
  FT_Face face;
  char* filepathname; // Defined through code that was excluded for the sake of simplifying this example

  FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
  FT_New_Face(ft, filepathname, 0, &face);
  FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, font_height);
  
  FT_Uint glyph_idx = FT_Get_Char_Index(face, 33);
  FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyph_index, FT_LOAD_RENDER);

  FT_Pos advance_x = face->glyph->advance.x;

  return 0;
}
```

Breaking at the end of `main()` results in advance_x being 1472.

Comment: "1472 is not the same as 467" is a meaningless comparison without any information about the respective units.

Comment: @molbdnilo And I wish I knew what to tell you in regards to the units. Dealing with font metrics is new to me. Are we talking about the em size? Something else? I know that `face->glyph->advance.x` is in 26.6 fractional pixel format, which means 1 unit is equal to 1/64th of a pixel.

Comment: You are changing the scale with FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes - so you advance.x depends on your font_height.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann That is helpful, but I still cant seem to get advance.x to match the 467 advance embedded in ARIALN.ttf. I have to provide some value in this function, and a font_height of 32 produces the closest advance.x of 448, still not 467 though. I have played with FT_Set_Char_Size() as well, utilizing a zero width an 32 * 64 height, which produces a similar result.

Comment: Where do you get the 467 from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated on that Tutorial, Step 2 page you linked in your question, those metrics are usually reported for a 26.6 pixel format.  You are modifying that by the way you're loading in the font.  You can use the [FT_LOAD_NO_SCALE](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#ft_load_no_scale) to "[not] scale the loaded outline glyph but keep it in font units."

Your code generates a bitmap version of the glyph at the size you've requested at a default screen resolution of 72 dpi.  The 1472 you're getting is the number of pixels * 64 used to draw the character in your bitmap.  So, in this case, 1472 / 64 = 23 pixels, which would be the distance you would advance your draw cursor/pen point if you were drawing multiple characters into the same bitmap.

The 467 is in 1/2048th vector units.  To make the conversion with a font_height of 100 pixels, it's: 467/2048 * 100 pixels, which is 22.8 pixels.  Round to 23 pixels.  Multiply by 64 to get 1472 1/64th pixels.

If you want to see it line up with the pixel value, set your font_height to 2048, then divide the resulting face->glyph->advance.x (29888) by 64, which will give 467.

The following script will give you the values you are looking for:

```c++
#include <string>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

using namespace std;

int main() {
  FT_Library ft;
  FT_Face face;
  string filepathname = "./arialn.ttf";

  FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
  FT_New_Face(ft, filepathname.c_str(), 0, &face);
  
  FT_UInt glyph_idx = FT_Get_Char_Index(face, '!');
  FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyph_idx, FT_LOAD_NO_SCALE);

  printf("width=%ld height=%ld\nhoriBearingX=%ld horiBearingY=%ld horiAdvance=%ld\n vertBearingX=%ld vertBearingY=%ld vertAdvance=%ld\n",face->glyph->metrics.width,face->glyph->metrics.height,face->glyph->metrics.horiBearingX,face->glyph->metrics.horiBearingY,face->glyph->metrics.horiAdvance,face->glyph->metrics.vertBearingX,face->glyph->metrics.vertBearingY,face->glyph->metrics.vertAdvance);
  FT_Pos advance_x = face->glyph->advance.x;
  printf("advance_x = %ld \n",advance_x);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
width=183 height=1466
horiBearingX=148 horiBearingY=1466 horiAdvance=467
vertBearingX=-85 vertBearingY=228 vertAdvance=1922
advance_x = 467
```